# how to make a button two lines text and icon vertically centered

Tags: html, css, button

[image]

how to make html button like this picture?
two line text.vertical centered.

here is my code

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #19d197;
}

.bz-fa-icon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-check bz-fa-icon"></i>
     Confirm<br>
     Return
</button>
```

Comment: pls do this.Best way is to do this with CSS since the image is actually a background for the text I suppose.

remove the image from inside the button
use css to decorate the button
place the text in the button
css:

button {
    background:transparent url(submit.png) no-repeat left top;
    width:50px;
    height:31px;
}

Answer (score 3):

Change some CSS

```
.btn {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #19d197;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.bz-fa-icon {
    left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8kwyjsho/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You can also wrap the text and span inside a div then wrap that div and img inside another div then add these classes:

also add display: inline-block; on your img

```css
.center {   
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%); 
    }
   .btnText {
      vertical-align: middle; 
      display: inline-block;
    }

body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.button {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 120px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
span {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #ccc;;
  display: block; 
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {  
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
   .btnText {
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="">
  <div class="center">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/30x30/cf97cf/fff">
      <div class="btnText">
        Button  
        <span>Button alt</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this code.

```html
.btn {
  width:80px;
  height:40px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #19d197;
}

.bz-fa-icon {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  margin-top:9px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox option:

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;  /* vertical alignment of items */
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 5px 13px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #19d197;
}

.inner {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-check bz-fa-icon"></i>
<div class="inner">Confirm <br /> Return</div>
</button>
```